# How to close all Finder inspector windows?

Tags: macos, finder

In Finder, I had a ton of files selected, and I ran *Get Info* instead of *Show Inspector*. This opens an info window for each file, instead of a single *multiple info window*.

How can I close every info window without restarting Finder ?

Comment: I just tested (Mac OS X Yosemite): you can save that Applescript line in an Applescript as an application, then drag it to your Finder's toolbar. Click it any time to close all info windows. Now if I knew how to close the View Options window (the one called up by Cmd-J), I'd add that to the script, too. Looking for that now.

Answer (score 7):

You could also run this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Finder" to close every information window
```

Answer (score 6):

Doing <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will close all windows at once.

This works for any window based Application.

Comment: I don't want to close Finder windows, just the info windows.

Comment: @Antoine Doing this will, indeed, close any open Finder windows but it will close, too, all the info windows.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember doing this in the past by command or alt clicking on the close button of the inspector window. Maybe in 10.6.